# Self-closing tags using createElement

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need to add a self-closing tag to XML file with DOM in PHP, but I don't know how, because standardly, this tag looks like this:

```
<tag></tag>
```

But it should look like this:

```
<tag/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DOM will do that automatically for you

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

will give by default

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo/>
```

unless you do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));
echo $dom->saveXml($dom, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

which would then give

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo></foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a `node` param to [`DOMDocument::saveXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#refsect1-domdocument.savexml-parameters) in order to output only a specific node, without any XML declaration:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = false;
$node = $doc->createElement('foo');

// Trimming the default carriage return char from output
echo trim($doc->saveXML($node));
```

will give

```
<foo/>
```

**not** containing any new line / carriage return ending char.