# PHP Create a xml file

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Create new XML file and write data to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038535/php-create-new-xml-file-and-write-data-to-it)
>   [PHP DOM method createElement need to be self-closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539551/php-dom-method-createelement-need-to-be-self-closing-tag)

i am trying to create a XML file with php, but i don`t know a commmand which creates the following:

```
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2">
    <graph mode="static" defaultedgetype="directed">
        <nodes>
            <node id="0" label="Hello" />  //I mena this Object
            <node id="1" label="Word" />
        </nodes>
        <edges>
            <edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
        </edges>
    </graph>
</gexf>
```

I'm talking about this child that doesn't consist of one opening statement and a close statement but just a single statement. Now I'm looking for a command that can create this kind of child (`<node/>`)

Comment: What's your current approach to the problem? :)

Comment: There're several built-in libraries to create XML. Care to explain which one you've chosen and what your current code looks like?

Comment: Simply by using addChild? Im guessing that you use simplexml http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: Why do you care if it produces `<foo />` or `<foo></foo>`? They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

1 - XML is just a text file. Just create a text file using `fopen` etc.

Or

2 -  Use the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) model to create the tree structure. You can then use this to create the file from that using the `saveXML` function.

It is entirely up to you.

Comment: Hello, i dont have a generall problem with creating xml files, i want to produce the element i have marked in the source code with //I mean this object, but i don`t even know which name it has so i can`t google it.