# php xml DOMDocument close tag element

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am using PHP DOMDocument() to generate XML file with elements.

I am appending all details into sample xml file into components tag. But closing tag is not coming. I want to create closing tag.

My Code is doing this

```
<component expiresOn="2022-12-31" id="pam" />
```

**I want to do like following**

```
<component expiresOn="2022-12-31" id="pam"></component>
```

My PHP CODE SAMPLE

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("Config.xml"); 
$components = $dom->getElementsByTagName('components')->item(0);

if(!empty($_POST["pam"])) {
    $pam = $_POST["pam"];
    $component = $dom->createElement('component');
    $component->setAttribute('expiresOn', $expirydate);
    $component->setAttribute('id', "pam");

    $components->appendChild($component5);
}

$dom->save("Config.xml");
```

I tested following suggestion and its not working. Both xml-php code are different.

```
$dom->saveXml($dom,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

[Self-closing tags using createElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539551/self-closing-tags-using-createelement)

I tested following.
[image]

Comment: Your original question was closed as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539551/self-closing-tags-using-createelement), which explains that you need to use `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` to avoid self-closing tags. You say you've tried the suggestion, but it still isn't shown in your code.

Comment: Yes sir. Please check screenshot of that. Plz guide me if i made any mistake,
Let me know if you want code sample in zip for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [`DOMDocument::saveXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) to save the new XML back into the original file, but all that function does is return the XML as a string. Since you aren't assigning the result to anything, nothing happens.

If you want to save the XML back to your file, as well as avoiding self-closing tags, you'll need to use the [`save`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) method as you originally were, and also pass the option:

```
$dom->save('licenceConfig.xml', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

See https://3v4l.org/e6N5s for a demo